# Android - simulating camera button press opens camera app but does not take picture

Tags: android, button, camera, simulate

I'm sending the following intents to simulate the hardware camera button press. This code is running in a service. The first time I run this code (being in a random screen) it opens the default camera app as expected. But If i run this code again while in the camera app it does not take a picture as i would expect. It just reloads the camera app. The question is:

What more do I have to do to make the default camera app take a picture ?(without user interaction).

```
      long eventtime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); 
      Intent downIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON, null); 
      KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, 
      KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA, 0); 
      downIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, downEvent); 
      sendOrderedBroadcast(downIntent, "android.permission.CAMERA"); 

      Intent upIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON, null); 
      KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime+100, eventtime+100, 
      KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA, 0); 
      upIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, upEvent); 
      sendOrderedBroadcast(upIntent, "android.permission.CAMERA");
```

(I don't think the permission is really necessary)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need CAMERA permission to open the camera app. But, there is no guarantee that the system will open a camera app on simulated camera press, this is a user-controlled preference.

You are encouraged to to use `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, as shown on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html):

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Even this code could load some other application, not the stock camera, due to the Android's   [open Intent model](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). Any app that has in it **AndroidManifest.xml** the following two lines in the `<intent-filter>` for some activity:

```
  <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

Comment: this just opens the camera app if ti exists..the user must click a button to take the picture. what I'm going for as I allready stated in the question is taking a picture without user interraction by simulating the camera button event. I know it is possible as I can do this with Tasker with a task that contains "open camera app","camera button press".

Comment: First, thanks for the tip. I will spend few following hours with _Tasker_.

Comment: Second, if you try it, you see that "Take Picture" action does not use the stock camera app. It launches a custom activity, and lets you choose the front or back facing camera, resolution, delay, whatnot.

Comment: I tried also to "Load App" and point to "Camera" app, but this does not use the camera button - the camera app is launched by package name. So far so good. I added a Button "Camera" press after 2 sec delay. This kind of works: _Tasker_ asks for Root access, which I grant. But the stock Camera app on my JellyBean device does not take pictures when it receives (maybe) the Camera Button click.